# Subdomain redirects to subdomain.domain.com/subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have some really strange behavior on my subdomain. 
When i enter my url in get redirected to a folder inside the subdomain.

**For example:**
When i enter: *subdomain*.domain.nl I get redirected to: *subdomain*.domain.nl/*subdomain*

I think is has something to do with this line of code inside my **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But I don't really know what to change so everything keeps redirected to https and i get rid of the redirecting inside the subdomain.

Comment: No, the rule you posted will _not_ result in the behavior you describe. It nowhere extracts the "subdomain" host name.

Comment: This sounds like you are using some form of hosting service. Most likely that service has installed a redirection rule to keep apart different http hosts. You will have to take a look into the service documentation or ask your service provider.